# Avoid users supplying null value to a Stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am curious why this will not work:

```
create procedure test
     @id int not null,
    @feature bit not null
```

It shows 'Incorrect syntax to be null' for the first line.

[I don't want to allow my users to supply a null value to the SP and hence trying to explicitly avoid the same.]

Comment: You need to check inside the stored procedure and return an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thank you. But there is there is no way of stopping users to supply null value to the SP at start ?

Comment: Unfortunately, @GordonLinoff is right. You have to do that in your SP code. You can check if any of params is NULL and then use `RAISERROR` to throw exception. Here's an example: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic560409-149-1.aspx

Comment: Side Note: I would seriously consider changing the public facing @feature bit variable to an int.  Then change it to an internal SqlDatatype of Bit from int.   An int datatype removes some ambiguity and allows you to control the -1 0 1   not zero concepts with more flexibility.   (I do a Not 0 logic usually)  Also this lets you provide a default if null.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was introduced in SQL Server 2014 by way of Natively Compiled Stored Procedures.  If you're not using 2014 yet, you will have to resort to other methods of prevention:

- Stop it from even getting to the database in code/the application logic (often times we don't have access to this though)
- Make the first part of you SP a null check and break out or throw an error if it is null
- Too many options to keep going...

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452286(v=sql.120).aspx